# Jquery fadeout hides all DIVS

Tags: jquery, html, woocommerce

I am using some jquery to hide some woocommerce div's by clicking on an appended button but I am having the issue where clicking the first one also closes the second (ie the woocommerce-message as well as the woocommerce-info div).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-message').append('<button class="hideme1">x</a>');
    $("button.hideme1").click(function() {
        $(".woocommerce-message").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-info').append('<button class="hideme2">x</a>');
    $("button.hideme2").click(function() {
        $(".woocommerce-info").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

I did have them together and tried splitting them up as well as using a different class for the button. Any pointers? Trying to learn this myself as I go so any help appreciated muchly!

Edit: This seems to work thanks to **Satpal** and **Rory**;

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-message').append('<button class="hideme">x</a>');
    $('.woocommerce-info').append('<button class="hideme">x</a>');
    $("button.hideme").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".woocommerce-message").fadeOut("slow");
        $("button.hideme").click(function() {
            $(".woocommerce-info").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    })
})
```

My jquery / js is as ugly as scrambled eggs!

Comment: Note that you don't need to use separate DOM ready handlers - both code blocks can be merged in to one

Comment: I do have to note that this doesnt work 100% as it requires 2 clicks to close the "child" element. I am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the parent element in the current element context.

```
$('.woocommerce-message').append('<button class="hideme1">x</a>');
$("button.hideme1").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".woocommerce-message").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thankyou kindly. Will read up on this. Have edited the original with code that works (hopefully correct?)